# Single return type from multiple plpqsql functions using JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, jooq

I have a number of plpgsql methods which all return the same custom type and other functions that return the same structure from as one of the tables.

When JOOQ generates the source for these instead of return the Table or UDT records that match the return type of the function it creates a new table record based on the function name.

Is this the only behavior?  Is there a way to get a single common table record or POJO back from these plpgsql calls which all have the same return type?

Edit: Below are two functions whose return type is a table and two more who return the same custom type.  The table and custom type end up unrelated to the generated code for the functions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS author CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE author (
  id              bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name      varchar(50),
  last_name       varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth   date,
  year_of_birth   integer,
  distinguished   boolean
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE book (
  id              bigint        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id       bigint        NOT NULL,
  title           varchar(400)  NOT NULL,
  length          integer       NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_book_author     FOREIGN KEY (author_id)   REFERENCES author(id)
);

DROP TYPE IF EXISTS authored_book CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE authored_book as (
  book_title           varchar(400),
  book_length          integer,
  author_first_name    varchar(50),
  author_last_name     varchar(50)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_my_favorite_authors(userId bigint) RETURNS SETOF author AS $_$
BEGIN
  return query select a.* from author a; -- where something or other
END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_editable_authors(adminId bigint) RETURNS SETOF author AS $_$
BEGIN
  return query select a.* from author a; -- where something or other
END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_short_books(maxLength integer) RETURNS SETOF authored_book AS $_$
BEGIN
  return query select b.title, b.length, a.first_name, a.last_name 
         from book b
         join author a on a.id = b.author_id
         where b.length <= maxLength;
END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_long_books(minLength integer) RETURNS SETOF authored_book AS $_$
BEGIN
  return query select b.title, b.length, a.first_name, a.last_name 
         from book b
         join author a on a.id = b.author_id
         where b.length >= minLength;
END
$_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Undoubtedly I am misunderstanding something as I can't even call the function correctly.  This works straight from the Author table:

```
public List<Author> jooqTest(Long companyId)
{
    return create.select().from(Tables.AUTHOR).fetchInto(Author.class);
}
```

But anything else I try like below that uses the routine give me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
public List<Author> jooqTest2(Long userId)
{
    return create.select().from(Routines.getMyFavoriteAuthors(userId)).fetchInto(Author.class);
}

public List<GetMyFavoriteAuthors> jooqTest3(Long userId)
{
    return create.select().from(Routines.getMyFavoriteAuthors(userId)).fetchInto(GetMyFavoriteAuthors.class);
}

public List<GetMyFavoriteAuthorsRecord> jooqTest4(Long userId)
{
    return create.select().from(Routines.getMyFavoriteAuthors(userId)).fetchInto(GetMyFavoriteAuthorsRecord.class);
}

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1483)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1461)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1453)
at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:123)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchOne(CursorImpl.java:1416)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.hasNext(CursorImpl.java:1384)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:206)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:181)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:260)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:341)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:290)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchInto(AbstractResultQuery.java:763)
at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchInto(SelectImpl.java:2731)
```

It seems I am not understanding something about postgresql functions in general.

Comment: Can you provide an example for such a function?

Comment: Lukas, thanks stopping by.  Sorry for wasting your time.  I was using 3.5.3 and my issues went away with 3.7.1.  Didn't realize how out of date I was.

Comment: Glad that the upgrade worked for you. Yes, we implemented quite a few bugfixes in the meantime, especially in this area. They're still due for the 3.5.x patch releases...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do exactly what I needed with this:

```
public List<Author> jooqTest2(Long userId)
{
    return create.select().from(Routines.getMyFavoriteAuthors(userId)).fetchInto(Author.class);
}
```

It just wasn't working in version 3.5.3, but the latest 3.7.1 worked fine.